# Memory management while copying objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copy, retaincount

I know that my question has already been discussed on StackOverflow but i found the answer not complete for my needs. So the question is:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: obj1,obj2,nil];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
```

what is retain count for the secondArray now? 2 or 1? Should i release it twice or just once?
Does copy or mutableCopy increases retain count of the COPYING (secondArray in this event) object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never care about the absolute retain count. Only that you're "balanced", that means for every `alloc`, `new*`, `copy`, `mutableCopy` and `retain` you need a corresponding `release` or `autorelease` (when not using ARC, that is).

If you apply this rule to each line you can see that your second line has an `alloc`, but there's no release. In fact, it's absolutely useless to allocate an instance here since you're not interested in it anyway. So it should simply read:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: obj1,obj2,nil];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
// There is no third line.
```

But let's discuss your original code and see what happened:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: obj1,obj2,nil];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
// secondArray points to a new instance of type NSMutableArray
secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
// You have copied another array (created a new NSMutableArray
// instance) and have overwritten the pointer to the old array.
// This means that the instance allocated in line 2 is still there
// (was not released) but you don't have a pointer to it any more.
// The array from line 2 has been leaked.
```

In Objective-C, we often speak of *ownership*: there are very few methods that make you the "owner" of an object. These are:

- `alloc`
- `new*`, as in `newFoo`
- `copy` and `mutableCopy`
- `retain`

If you call these, you get an object for which you are *responsible*. And that means you need to call a corresponding number of `release` and/or `autorelease` on these objects. For example, you're fine if you do `[[obj retain] retain];` and then `[[obj autorelease] release];`

Comment: I'd add that you have two objects which are owned and need to be released at some stage. And you're right - the `retainCount` is unimporant - only worry about balancing owning calls with releasing calls.

Comment: Actually secondArray has been allocated and used somewhere far away in the code. I wrote it in second line just for convenience. So if i got you right in order to avoid memory leaks i should release secondArray first and this would be absolutely valid?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha: You only release the object pointed to by `secondArray` once you're finished with it. `release` means: *From this line on, I won't be needing that object any more; it may be deallocated.* `autorelease` means: *Soon, I won't be needing it any more; but it should stay alive at least until I leave this method.* (That's not 100% correct but close enough to the truth to be useful)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: obj1,obj2,nil];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
```

What is happening is that you've created a memory leak. You just lost the reference assigned to secondArray when you overwrote it with the mutableCopy of firstArray with this line.

```
secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
```

If you then release secondArray twice, the program will crash because you're then overreleasing the mutable array assigned by

```
secondArray = [firstArray mutableCopy];
```

What you need to do is to make sure you're not overwriting retained references by mistake, and balance retains with releases.